# Python - Open multiple files and output filename

Tags: python, file

I am fairly new to Python and am working on a project for work. My goal is to take
files from a directory and if inside the file the word failed exists, it will output
that file name to my output text file and then move on to the next file.

```
for file in os.listdir('directory i am pulling files from'):

    #if file extension is .log, open file and save filename
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.log'):
        logFile = open('*.log', 'r')
        fileName = os.path.basename(logFile)
    
        #if string 'failed' is somewhere in the file, open output file /
        #and insert the filename into the output file /
        #once done, close both the log file and output file
        if 'failed' in logFile.read():
            outputFile = open('C:\Allowed\logError_output.txt', 'a')
            outputFile.write('write the filename')
            outputFile.close()
            logFile.close()
    
        #if file does not have 'failed' in contents /
        #close log file
        else:
            logFile.close()
```

'''

Comment: What's your question? Does your script not work as you expected it to? If so, how do the results differ from what you want?

Comment: The code does not output anything. However there are no errors or obvious issues I'm missing from a first glance. I am wondering if theoretically my code works but if there's something I'm missing from it putting the file name into the output file

Comment: Still not clear what your issue is. Does it do what you want? If so, you wouldn't be asking here. What did you expect your code to do and what are you getting instead? We cannot guess what your problem is.

Comment: The goal of the program is for it to output the filename of the file being read if the file contains the word failed anywhere in it. However, when I run it, nothing gets outputted into the file like it's supposed to. I have tried, outputting using a print statement however nothing gets printed either. So, my question is, why is nothing being sent to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no file named "*.log" in your directory, you should get a FileNotFoundError. If, by change, there is such a file, then you never see the real problem:
The line `logFile = open('*.log', 'r')` should be `logFile = open(file, 'r')`.

Comment: I do see what you mean. I switched my log file however it did not change the issue. I am wondering if there is something wrong with my second if statement.

Comment: You should also delete the line with the broken assignment to fileName. It causes a TypeError on my machine. Wondering why that is not the case when you execute the code...

Comment: I will delete that right now. I have no idea why it is not giving me a TypeError. The reason I had that was because before without that, my program was still not outputting the file name so I thought that might pull the name of the current open file so that I can output it to the text file